# BlackJack Application. All menu options work except for the first option to actually play the game

Tags: c++

I wrote a Black jack application in C++ and for some reason, when I choose the first option to play a game, it doesn't play. All other menu options work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

#include <conio.h>

#include "Card.h"

#include <vector> // Stadard Template Library (STL)

using namespace std;



string showCards( vector<Card> cards);

short sumCardValues( vector<Card> cards);



int main()

{

    short cash = 100;

    cout << "Welcome to Kyle's BlackJack Extreme! " << endl;

    cout << "\nYou are starting out with $ " << cash << endl;



    cout << "\nPress any key to continue... ";

    _getch();



    short choice = 0;



    do

    {



        system("cls");

        cout << "Menu\n" << endl;

        cout << "1) Play a hand" << endl;

        cout << "2) Show current cash balance" << endl;

        cout << "3) Exit" << endl;



        cout << "\nEnter your choice: ";

        cin >> choice;



        switch (choice)

        {

        case 1:

            cout << "\nPlaying a hand..." << endl;

            break;

        case 2:

            cout << "\nYour current cash balance: $" << cash << endl;

            break;

        case 3:

            cout << "\nThank you for playing Kyle's Extreme BlackJack! " << endl;

            cout << "\nYour final cash position: $ " << cash << endl;

            break;

        default:

            cout << "\nError. Please select from the menu. " << endl;

            break;

        }

        cout << "\nPress any key to continue...";

        _getch();

    } while (choice != 3);



    return 0;

}



/// Show the cards in the vector (resizable aray)

string showCards(vector<Card> cards)

{

    string output = "";

    for (Card c : cards)

    {

        output += c.toString() + " ";

    }

    return output;

}



/// Add up the total value of the cards

short sumCardValues(vector<Card> cards)

{

    short total = 0;

    for (Card c : cards)

    {

        total += c.getValue();  // total = total + c.getValue();

    }



    return total;



}



/// Play a single hand of BlackJack

void playHand(short &cash)

{

    // create two ArrayLists that can hold Card objects

    // an AAraylist is a seizable array

    // in C++, the ArrayList is called a vector

    vector<Card> dealerCards;

    vector<Card> playerCards;

    short dealerCardsTotal = 0;

    short playerCardsTotal = 0;



    // get be amount

    short bet = 0;

    cout << "\nEnter bet amount: ";

    cin >> bet;



    // create two cards for the dealer and show the first one

    int number;

    Card card1;

    Card card2;

    dealerCards.push_back(card1);

    dealerCards.push_back(card2);

    dealerCardsTotal = sumCardValues(dealerCards);



    cout << "\nDealer is showing: " << dealerCards[0].toString() << endl;



    // create two cards for the player and show them both

    playerCards.push_back(Card()); // create the card and put it directly into the ArrayList (vector)

    playerCards.push_back(Card());

    playerCardsTotal = sumCardValues(playerCards);



    cout << "\nHere are your cards: " << showCards(playerCards) << endl;



    // give cards to the player until they stand ('S')

    char answer = '?';



    do

    {

        cout << "\nDo you want to hit or stand (H/S)? ";

        cin.sync(); // flush the input stream (keyboard buffer) -- cin.ignore(100, '\n')

        cin >> answer;

        cin.sync();



        if (toupper(answer) == 'H')

        {

            // give a card to the player

            Card c;

            cout << "\nYou were dealt this card: " << c.toString() << endl;

            playerCards.push_back(c); // add card to Player's hand



                                      // sum up the card values

            playerCardsTotal = sumCardValues(playerCards);



            // did the player bust?

            if (playerCardsTotal > 21)

            {

                // do you have an Ace that can be dropped to a 1 value?

                for (Card c : playerCards)

                {

                    if (c.getValue() == 11)

                    {

                        cout << "\nYour total is " << playerCardsTotal << endl;

                        c.flipAceToOne();

                        cout << "However, you have an Ace that was converted to '1' value" << endl;

                        playerCardsTotal = sumCardValues(playerCards);

                        cout << "\nYour new total is " << playerCardsTotal << endl;



                        // if we are good now, break out of the loop. otherwise, keep looping and looking for Aces

                        if (playerCardsTotal <= 21)

                            break;

                    }

                }

            }

            // show the cards and the total

            cout << "\nHere are your cards: " << showCards(playerCards) << endl;

            cout << "Your total is " << playerCardsTotal << endl;



            // if busted, stop the loop

            if (playerCardsTotal > 21)

                answer = 'S';

        }

    } while (toupper(answer) != 'S');



    // if player's cardTotal is more than 21, the player busted so take money away

    if (playerCardsTotal > 21)

    {

        cout << "\nYou busted!" << endl;

        cash = cash - bet;

    }

    else

    {

        // player stands so the dealer hits until 17 or greater

        do

        {

            if (dealerCardsTotal < 17)

            {

                Card c;

                cout << "\nDealer was dealt: " << c.toString() << endl;

                dealerCards.push_back(c); // add the card to the dealer's hand

                cout << "\nDealer cards: " << showCards(dealerCards) << endl;

                dealerCardsTotal = sumCardValues(dealerCards);

                cout << "Dealer total: " << dealerCardsTotal << endl;

            }

        } while (dealerCardsTotal < 17);



        // show the cards for the dealer and the player

        cout << "\nYour cards: " << showCards(playerCards) << " (" << playerCardsTotal << ")" << endl;

        cout << "\nDealer cards: " << showCards(dealerCards) << "(" << dealerCardsTotal << ")" << endl;



        // who wins?

        if (dealerCardsTotal > 21)

        {

            cout << "\nDealer Busted!" << endl;

            cash = cash + bet;

        }

        else if (dealerCardsTotal > playerCardsTotal)

        {

            cout << "\nDealer Wins." << endl;

            cash = cash - bet;

        }

        else if (playerCardsTotal > dealerCardsTotal)

        {

            cout << "\nYou win!" << endl;

            cash = cash + bet;

        }

        else

        {

            cout << "\nYour pushed the dealer (tie)." << endl;

        }

    }



    // show the current cash position

    cout << "\nYour current cash balance: $" << cash << endl;



}



Card.H

#pragma once



#include <ctime>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string>

using namespace std;





class Card

{

private:

    // attributes

    char suit;

    char face;

    short value;



    static bool randomizerSeeded;   // class-wide variable (one copy in memory is shared by all Card objects)



public:

    // constructor and destructor

    Card();

    ~Card();



    // behaviors

    string toString();

    bool flipAceToOne();



    // accessors and mutators

    inline char getSuit() { return suit; }

    inline char getFace() { return face; }

    inline short getValue() { return value; }

};



Card.cpp

#include "Card.h"



bool Card::randomizerSeeded = false;







Card::Card()

{

    // seed the randomizer only once for all card objects

    if( !randomizerSeeded )  //if (randomizerSeeded == false)

    {

        srand(time(NULL));

        randomizerSeeded = true;

    }





    short min = 3;

    short max = 6;

    suit = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;



    

    min = 2;

    max = 14;

    short number = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;



    if (number >= 2 && number <= 9)

    {

        value = number;

        face = number + 48;

    }

    else if (number == 10)

    {

        value = number;

        face = 'T';

    }

    else if (number == 11)

    {

        value = 10;

        face = 'J';

    }

    else if (number == 12)

    {

        value = 10;

        face = 'Q';

    }

    else if (number == 13)

    {

        value = 10;

        face = 'K';

    }

    else if (number == 14)

    {

        value = 11;

        face = 'A';

    }

    else

    {

        value = -1;

        face = 'E';

    }

}



Card::~Card()

{

}



string Card::toString()

{

    string output = "";

    output += suit;

    output += face;

    return output;

}



bool Card::flipAceToOne()

{

    if (value == 11)

    {

        value = 1;

        return true;

    }

    else

    {

        return false;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case to play a hand, you never call the playHand() function.

```
case 1:

        cout << "\nPlaying a hand..." << endl;

        break;
```

Adding this call will fix that issue.

```
playHand(cash)
```

Comment: Thank you cynthi8! This solved my issue. I have no idea why I did that. By you pointing it out made me realize how small of a mistake this was, but also made my program not work. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Small mistakes are often the hardest to find :)